# How to reverse gravity immediately?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, interpolation

I'm making a 2D game. I have a Cube Object falling down from the top of the screen, and I have pipes which the cube should pass by reversing gravity.

Well my object is falling down from the top of the screen. I tap on the screen to reverse gravity but it's not going immediately up: it takes time to change the gravity orientation. When i tap the screen my object continues falling and then goes up. My movement is forming the shape of a `U` when I tap the screen. The same thing happens when it goes up: I tap it to go down and in that case my movement forms the shape of a `∩`.

What I want to achieve is that when I tap the screen my object's movement has instant response.

In addition, I want some sort of attenuation, damping, or smoothing.

I've tried these examples without success:

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.Lerp.html

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Vector3.SmoothDamp.html

This is my code:

```
public class PlayerControls : MonoBehaviour
{
     public GameObject playerObject = null;
Rigidbody2D player;

public float moveSpeed;
public float up;

Vector2 targetVelocity;



void Start()
{
    player = playerObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

    // Set the initial target velocity y component to the desired up velocity.
    targetVelocity.y = up;
}

void Update()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(i);

        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended && touch.tapCount == 1)
        {
            // Flip the target velocity y component.
            targetVelocity.y = -targetVelocity.y;
        }
    }
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    // Ensure if moveSpeed changes, the target velocity does too.
    targetVelocity.x = moveSpeed;

    // Change the player's velocity to be closer to the target.
    player.velocity = Vector2.Lerp(player.velocity, targetVelocity, 0.01f);
}
```

}
This script is attached to the falling cube.

Comment: P.S. I'm new to unity programming guys . :)

Comment: Based on the code you've given I don't see a reason it would do anything I would imagine as "snapping". Can you describe what happens more clearly? (Edit: I see now the long edit history of this question... maybe the question's meaning changed somewhere in there? I'd suggest reading through it again to make sure it represents your problem accurately.)

Comment: @ 31eee384  Well my object is falling down from the top of the screen .I tap on the screen to reverse gravity but its not going immediately up it takes time to change the gravity orientation.When i tap the screen happens this:  \

Comment: @ 31eee384  Well my object is falling down from the top of the screen .I tap on the screen to reverse gravity but its not going immediately up it takes time to change the gravity orientation.Instead when i tap the screen   my object continues falling and then going up.My movement is forming the shape of "U" when i tap the screen.  The same thing when it goes up I tap it to go down in that case my movement forms the shape of a rainbow.Yes I've edited a lot but i didn't change the question my issue is the same. I hope you understand my issue and help me.

Comment: Well, it doesn't matter if your issue has remained the same, because the question doesn't seem to describe it. I think you should edit (potentially rewrite) the question to be **very** clear about what's **currently** happening and what your desired goal is.

Comment: @31eee384 is it better now?

Comment: @ 31eee384  Thanks but can you help me a little bit with the code  as I am a novice coder.

Comment: What you're describing is actually how gravity *would* work and be observed providing you could actually change it in a real environment. Your object has speed downwards, it's exactly like if you threw an object into the air, what you want apparently is that as soon as the object left your hand it would start moving downwards, but that is not how gravity works. Gravity will accelerate the object downwards which will first have to counter the initial upwards (or downwards in your case) motion before it starts falling the other direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When affected by a constant force (in your code, gravity), an object will move in a parabola. You're observing a parabola: that `U` shape. To avoid the parabola and get instant response (a `V` shape), don't use forces. Replace the `gravityScale` code with something like:

```
Vector2 velocity = player.velocity;
velocity.y = -velocity.y;
player.velocity = velocity;
```

This inverts the velocity's y component, making the player move upwards.

---

You also mentioned you want to smooth this out. I suggest adding another variable: the target velocity.

To implement this, add `Vector2 targetVelocity` to your component. Then, during each `FixedUpdate` you can interpolate from the current velocity towards the target velocity to gradually change speed. Replace this line in your current code:

```
player.velocity = new Vector2(moveSpeed, player.velocity.y);
```

With this:

```
player.velocity = Vector2.Lerp(player.velocity, targetVelocity, 0.01f);
```

This will slowly change the velocity to be the same as the target velocity, smoothing out the movement. `0.01f` is the place between the old velocity and the new velocity that the player's velocity is set to. Choose a larger number to interpolate more quickly, and a smaller number to change direction more slowly.

Then, instead of changing `velocity` when the screen is tapped, change `targetVelocity`. Make sure that the `x` component of `targetVelocity` is equal to `moveSpeed`, or the object won't move horizontally at all!

---

Combining these two changes, the `Start` and `FixedUpdate` methods should look similar to this:

```
void Start()
{
    player = playerObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

    // Set the initial target velocity y component to the desired up velocity.
    targetVelocity.y = up;
}

void Update()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(i);

        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended && touch.tapCount == 1)
        {
            // Flip the target velocity y component.
            targetVelocity.y = -targetVelocity.y;
        }
    }
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    // Ensure if moveSpeed changes, the target velocity does too.
    targetVelocity.x = moveSpeed;

    // Change the player's velocity to be closer to the target.
    player.velocity = Vector2.Lerp(player.velocity, targetVelocity, 0.01f);
}
```

---

Note that you shouldn't use `Input` in `FixedUpdate`, because inputs are updated every frame and `FixedUpdate` may run multiple times per frame. This could cause the input to be read twice, especially if the frame rate gets slower and the fixed update is more likely to need to run multiple times per frame.

Comment: Should my player be Kinematic.Despite that, this doesn't work maybe I've written it wrong.The code you've written i should replace it with the "gravityScale" in the "for loop" "if statement " right?

Comment: @AbduOmar [Kinematic rigidbodies](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Rigidbody.html) will not be affected by physics, and `velocity` is part of physics, so it will not be applied on a kinematic object. So no, it shouldn't be kinematic. For your second part, yes, you should replace the `gravityScale` code. If you can't get this working, you should add the new code to the question with an edit so I can change my answer to be more accurate.

Comment: I edited my question you can check it.But with this code when i tap the screen nothing the players keep forwardly falling without responding. :)

Comment: Look now at my question I've edited it again.With this script  when i press the screen it hops like flappy bird but i don't want to achieve that .I want when i tap the screen  my object to infinetely go up until i press it again to go infinetely down.I hope you understand.:)

Comment: @AbduOmar I've added a concrete example. It looks to me like you need to understand the code better--the changes you made don't make much sense.

Comment: It works perfectly thanks a lot.But there is a bug or glitch.So it works perfectly I'm tapping on the screen and my object is interpolating.But in one moment i tap and it doesn't respond and it keeps going up or down(it depends).I mean it doesn't respond at all and afterwards i die.When i start again  it is normal again but at a moment it stops.How can i fix it?I hope you understand my question now.:)

Comment: Did you understand my issue ? If not i will try to explain it again :)

Comment: @AbduOmar I'm not sure. You might not be receiving touches, or receiving 2 or 4 at the same time. Maybe `tapCount` is no longer one? You need to do some debugging--I can't help much with that.

Comment: Ok I will try debugging and then coment here what I achieved :)

Comment: I couldn't find a solution of this issue :(.I changed 'tapCount' to more and equal to one.But it is the same.

Comment: And I want you to know that the time that you've written "0.1f" if i change it to number 50 or any other number the velocity of interpolation is the same.I t doesn't change.It isn't slower or faster it changes the same  on every number.

Comment: @AbduOmar I realized it's probably because you're reading input in `FixedUpdate`, which can be run multiple times per frame. And this effect would be more visible when more things are on screen, likely what happens in your game. Re: `Lerp`, it's a number between 0 to 1, so `50` won't be any different than `1`. It should definitely have an effect between 0 and 1 though. Try powers of 10 to see large effects: 0.01f, 0.001f, etc.

Comment: Check I've edited my question.Look with this script it doesn't respond at all.

Comment: No wait my bad I just had to increase the 0.1f to 1